# Printing PDF file is missing characters

Tags: printing, fonts, pdf, evince

I open a PDF-file in Document Viewer (Evince) 44.1 in Ubuntu 23.10, and it looks perfect. But when I try to print it, a lot of text/chars is missing. The properties for the PDF file says "All fonts are ether standard or embedded".

If I send it to the printer, I get random chars where the Preview are missing text/chars.

If I send the print to "create file" I get a new pdf-file, looking like the print preview.

What can I do?

[Screenshot showing PDF file, Properties for the PDF-file and a Print Preview window], showing lots of text missing [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbSuN.png)

Comment: Have you checked to see that the fonts are actually missing or are they possibly the same color as the background? I guess you could test this by creating the new pdf-file and then try to highlight or select where the fonts/text is missing to see if it highlights text that is unseen.

Comment: Also, this isn't a solution but a workaround: have you tried printing the pdf from Gimp? Printing PDF files from Gimp is the only way I've ever been able to get a true print of an actual PDF file. For example, when printing sewing patterns that are calibrated to a certain size, printing from Gimp is the only way I've ever been able to get a printed inch, the exact length of an actual inch as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem, but I've discovered that printing from the PDF viewer in Google Chrome works fine.  This is on a Ricoh MP 5054 PDF printer.